# ASP msxml3.dll error '80072efe'

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2005, asp-classic

I'm getting this error on one of the ASP pages of our site.

> *msxml3.dll error '80072efe'*
>
> *The connection with the server was terminated abnormally*

The error refers to this line in the ASP, which essentially is just posting some info back into a page after the user selects an option from the dropdown:

> xmlHTTP.Send strFormData

I searched for a solution to the error and saw several responses which I didn't really understand. Some suggested adding *SNAT* to the server, some talked about using *Server.Transfer* and others talked about it being a Firewall issue. [I tried reconfiguring the Firewall to allow all incoming TCP connections to all ports. Didn't solve the issue]

I'm sort of inexperienced when it comes to server issues so I don't wanna make any changes in server configs or production DB unless there's a clear answer/solution to this. I'm running MS SQL Server Management Studio Express 2005.

Any help on this will be highly appreciated. Let me know if you need any other information.

Thanks.

Comment: That's using HTTP to POST to a URL so the first thing to do is check that the URL is working and accepting whatever data is in `strFormData`

Comment: Thanks for your reply Alex K.

It is... It's a payment system with 4 options. It's just selecting 1 option which is causing this error. The site and control and behaving as expected for all other options.